# Looping with multiple variables in a URL using Postman

Tags: loops, csv, variables, postman

Using postman tool, I am trying to loop in multiple values in the place of a specific parameter 'memid' in the sample URL https://www.testdomain.com/login?memid=123

I have replaced the value '123' as {{id}} in the URL and then declared a single value '123' in Globals. It's working fine when I execute this. But, is there a way where I can loop the URL and replace the variable memid every time with some other predefined unique values? Should I be storing all the values in a separate csv file?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at using a Data file in the Collection Runner to help with this - More information can be found here.

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files/